# Using index from a list to get another value/element in another list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, indexing

I have project wherein I have to get the index of certain element in a list, then use that index to get another value in another list.

For example,

```
j_set = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
on_going = [1]
e_list = [[], [1], [1], [2], [3], [3], [5], [4, 7], [6], [8, 9], [10]]
```

So far, the code looks like this:

```
if isinstance(on_going, int):
    on_going = [on_going]
idx = [y for y, x in enumerate(e_list) if x in on_going] # code to get index in e_list
print(idx)

for i in idx:
    q_active = j_set.append(i)
    print(q_active)
```

The objective is to get the corresponding `index` of value/element in `on_going` from `e_list`. Then, use that index to get corresponding activity from `j_set` and store in `q_active`.

```
Expected output:
q_active = [2, 3]
```

The problem is, with the code above, I am getting an output for storing values in q_active as:

```
[1, 2] #idx output
None
None
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: please add input and expected output

Comment: @HarshaBiyani edited my post already. Input is actually the value in on_going. So for, on_qoing = 1, it will try to look for its 'match' in e_list and get the index of that match. Using that index, get its corresponding value in j_set then store in q_active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps use a list_comprehension:

```
print([j_set[item] for i in on_going for item in range(len(e_list)) if i in e_list[item]])
#[2, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `enumerate` to get index and data from list:

```
e_list = [[], [1], [1], [2], [3], [3], [5], [4, 7], [6], [8, 9], [10]]
for data_index, data_val in enumerate(e_list):
  print(data_index, data_val)
  # write business logic here
```